# split hibernate entities across tables by ID

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible to split hibernate objects to tables across tables ?
My motivation is to enable `TRUNCATE` and batch imports to tables without touching other data, and to allow easier index rebuilding.

Comment: if there you go, only pain will you find.  Listen to Mark.

Answer (score 3):

I'll present my opinion here. I think there are many different ways/directions you can check:

1. Just create partition on table. Then Database will manage everything for you.
2. Use Hibernate Shards project. I'm not sure its up-to-date with the recent hibernate versions though.
3. Check out Hibernate inheritance strategies. One of the strategies will allow you to create object hierarchy at the level of Java Entities and they'll be mapped to different tables.